# Erro EEXIST Aplicação Electron

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

Empacotei uma aplicação desenvolvida em Node js + SQLITE + Electron.

Se eu empacotar sem o ASAR, o executável funciona normal, se eu coloco o ASAR, ele me retorna este erro ao fazer uma consulta no Banco de Dados.

Erro completo: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir ****'C:\Users\dougn\Documents\Projetos\realease\sigtapp-win32-x64\resources\app.asar'"}****

Empacotei usando o comando: **electron-packager sigtapp sigtapp --overwrite --asar --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --prune=true --out=realease****

Segue o package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sigtapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "adm-zip": "^0.5.9",
    "cls-hooked": "^4.2.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "decompress": "^4.2.1",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "formidable": "^1.2.6",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "readline": "^1.3.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.9.0",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "v8-compile-cache": "^2.3.0",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^15.3.0",
    "electron-builder": "^22.13.1",
    "electron-packager": "^15.4.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.14"
  }
}
```

Li na documentação mas não consegui resolver, alguém passou por isso?
Obrigado.